# Automatically redirect to login page when session time out in Spring boot HttpSession

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpsession

In Spring boot application. When session timeout, logout the user and redirect to login page. When the user logs in again then navigate to the last visited page. I am using JDBC `HttpSession`. Please help me with how to handle this.

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String home(Model model, HttpSession session) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> messages = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("MY_SESSION_MESSAGES");

    if (messages == null) {
        messages = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    model.addAttribute("sessionMessages", messages);
    System.out.println("Session Det ------------------" + model.toString());
    return "index";
}

@PostMapping("/persistMessage")
public String persistMessage(@RequestParam("msg") String msg, HttpServletRequest request) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> msgs = (List<String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("MY_SESSION_MESSAGES");
    if (msgs == null) {
        msgs = new ArrayList<>();
        request.getSession().setAttribute("MY_SESSION_MESSAGES", msgs);
    }
    msgs.add(msg);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("MY_SESSION_MESSAGES", msgs);
    return "redirect:/";
}

@PostMapping("/destroy")
public String destroySession(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    return "logout";
}
```

Comment: Is there any user interaction (e.g. click) ?

Comment: yes..interaction  is there

Comment: yes..After Session timeout, when user refresh or click any option in the page then navigate to login page.

Comment: what are your efforts and what have you tried so far. please do share that as well.

Comment: you need to store user last visited page in database ,whenever session timeout and user refresh the page you can redirect user to login page and when user login again  you can find last visited page from database and you can redirect/forward user to that page. In second approach you can manage timer on javascript end  and after logout time you can call logout url from ajax if you do not want to wait user for page refresh.

Comment: Just i am created sample application. nothing is implemented. I will share my code